# RewriteRule for Paypal IPNs

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to set up a RewriteRule to pass on Paypal IPN notifications from an old URL to a new one that will capture it and interpret it, so I need all of the variables and such passed onto the new url (IPN notification shouldn't be parsed or processed, just passed onto the new url).

What is the best/most reliable RewriteRule/Condition I should use in this case?

Right now I just have this in the old file that still receives IPN notifications:

```
<?php header("Location: /payment/paypal/ipn"); exit; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it on your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule oldipnreceiver.php newipnreceiver.php? [QSA]
```

Comment: I want to use RewriteRules in .htaccess file, as I don't want to rely on the physical file itself... it's failed me once already (got rewritten/erased). But the above header redirection works just fine for now. I'd just rather replace it with an .htaccess redirection instead.

Comment: that seems to work just fine for now... will be testing it with live IPNs in the meantime. Thanks!